# Adjust imageview size according to image coming from server and then adjusting other labels

Tags: swift, image, uitableview, uiimageview, size

I am having a tableview cell containing an ImageView, two labels. I need to adjust the size of image view in accordance with the image coming from server and then adjust the labels.

Please refer to the cell screen shot.

[image]

I am downloading image using

```
cell.imageViewKnowledgeFeed.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlStr as String), completed: { (image, error,imageCacheType , nil) in
        cell.imageViewKnowledgeFeed.image = image
        print(image?.size)
        cell.imageViewKnowledgeFeed.frame = CGRect(x: cell.imageViewKnowledgeFeed.frame.origin.x,
                                                   y: 100,
                                                   width: cell.imageViewKnowledgeFeed.frame.size.width,
                                                   height: cell.imageViewKnowledgeFeed.frame.size.height)
        //  tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    })
```

Constraints are as follows

[image]

I am using content mode `AspectFill` into `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create outlets for constraints and they set them programmatically in accordance with size of the image and afterwards you can call layoutSubviews() to adjust other labels and associated designs.